# freeze_graph.py usage in Tensorflow 1.0

Tags: tensorflow

I was able to use freeze_graph.py with tensorflow 0.11 when the ckpt files that I managed to create were just two files (save.ckpt-100000 and save.ckpt-100000.meta).  Now when I use tensorflow 1.0 to make a model, it is saving three files (save.ckpt-100000-data-00000-of00001, save.ckpt-100000.index, and save.ckpt-100000.meta).

When I try the following script it works with tensorflow 0.11 but doesn't work with tensorflow 1.0.

"python freeze_graph.py --input_graph=myinputgraph.pb --input_checkpoint=save.ckpt-100000 --output_graph=frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=add,Reshape_2"

I've tried changing the input_checkpoint to save.ckpt-100000.data-00000-of-00001, save.ckpt-100000.index, and save.ckpt-100000.meta.  None work. Is freeze_graph.py no longer working?  Or does it operate in a different way now?

Comment: change `--input_checkpoint=save.ckpt-100000` into `--input_checkpoint=save.ckpt` and have a try

Comment: That gives the message  "Input checkpoint 'save.ckpt' doesn't exist!"

Comment: I believe some earlier versions of TensorFlow had a bug where you had to add `./` to the beginning of a checkpoint path. Can you try changing the flag to `--input_checkpoint=./save.ckpt-100000`? (If this works, you might also be able to fix the problem by upgrading to a later version of TensorFlow.)